# Installing AMD fglrx 15-201-2401 on ubuntu 14.04.4 lts 64-bit on HP Z420 with FirePro W9100 GPU

Tags: graphics, amd-processor

I have successfully installed fglrx driver 15-201-2401 on Oracle Linux 7.2 and SUSE 12 SP1. All I added from my default installation are gcc and kernel-devel packages.

I just installed ubuntu 14.4.04 64-bit on same workstation on separate disk. Both linux-headers and kernel-headers are installed as well as gcc.

I am now looking for the equivalent of kernel-devel in ubuntu 14.04 which I think I need as is the case with Oracle Linux or SUSE. I tried:

```
aptitude search kernel
aptitude search linux
```

and I don't see it.

Currently, my installation fails which I believe is due to missing kernel-devel.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install a driver this way.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

And exactly this driver will be installed.